# php + mysql построение графика

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

есть две даты, и запрос на php

```
"select count(id) as count_u from orders where date between ".POST['date_min']." and ".POST['date_max'].""
```

как вывести вот такую (примерно диаграмму) ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Библиотеку какую нибудь возьмите, лучше джаваскиптовую. они обычно просто массив данных на вход принимают и сами отрисовывают. https://habrahabr.ru/post/246907/

Comment: Вот это может?

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic

Comment: а как указыват диапазон дат? я так понял сколько в data столько и дат будет делать

Comment: и как сделать даты вот такого типа 2017-07-12

я пробовал но не хочет так работать